# flextable throws error when saving a table to docx with equations in a column

Tags: r, flextable

### Example

I have this equation column in my table that when I convert to `flextable` and save to a `docx` file, it throws an error. However, the same table is successfully saved to html. But unfortunately, when I try to copy the contents of the saved table from the html file, this equation column is not selected as it seems that it is rendered as an image.
In the following example, I am showing only that 1 column that is the source of the error. IS there any possibility to save it directly to a `docx` file? Thank you.

```
library(flextable)

paramz_namez <- c("T", "A_i", "b", "v_0", "\\delta", "s_0", "k", "A_+", "A_-", "\\lambda", "a_{BL}", "p_{BL}", "M", "\\tau_p", "\\tau_m", "\\sigma_n", "\\sigma_m", "\\Delta{T}", "G_std", "\\Delta{T}_{p0}", "\\Delta{T}_{p1}", "H_std")

ftt <- flextable(data.frame(Parameter = paramz_namez))

ftt <- compose(
  x = ftt, j = "Parameter",
  value = as_paragraph(as_equation(Parameter, width = 2, height = .5)))


flextable::save_as_docx(ftt, path = "params.docx")

Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  error parsing attribute name [68]
```

Comment: Have you installed the `equatags` package and run `equatags::mathjax_install()` as suggested in the docs? After doing so your code runs fine on my Mac and gives the desired result.

Comment: @stefan, thank you! After running `equatags::mathjax_install()`, I can save the table to `docx` with the equation column successfully.